# How to use "relative" URLs?

Tags: php, html

i have a doubt, in an HTML file I have the following structure:

```
    MAIN -> index.php
         -> IMAGES -> image.jpg
```

In an 'img' tag should I use this:

```
    <img src="IMAGES/image.jpg">
```

Or this?

```
    <img src="/IMAGES/image.jpg">
```

Note that in the second example I added the slash before IMAGES. This is my question.

Comment: the first one is "in my current directory, look in a subdirectory called 'images'". the second one is "at the root directory of my URL space, look for a subdir calls images". There's no right/wrong answer, it entirely depends on how you've structured your site.

Answer (score 3):

Both work in that case, but I suggest to use your first option (relative path), so if in the future you move your entire project under a new root dir, all your site will continue working.

Comment: So I should use slashes right? The problem is that I've tried to change all relative paths to ones with slash (css and js files) but all of them stopped working.

Comment: @CainãMaturo When you use the slash make sure to use the **full path from the web root**.

Comment: I'm talking about your first option `<img src="IMAGES/image.jpg">` which is the one that don't uses a slash as first character in the path, so, it's a relative path, that is better than using absolute path because some times you don't control the root dir where your web application will be served.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that? I also always find an error using 'mod_rewrite' so i have to use <base href>, is there a way to don't need this?

Answer (score 1):

Both would work but if you don't expect to ever move your IMAGES directory, go with `/IMAGES/image.jpg`.  This would be preferable because you'll be able to use that same uri anywhere in your markup (say, if you add `MAIN/SCRIPTS/newscript.php`, then `/IMAGES..` will work, `IMAGES/image.jpg` would not).  If, however, you always intend to store IMAGES as a directory at the same level as index.php, but you might end up moving index.php somewhere else, then you might consider using `IMAGES/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, they're exactly the same, but consider this updated example:

```
    MAIN -> index.php
         -> ABOUT -> index.php
         -> IMAGES -> image.jpg
```

Now, inside ABOUT/index.php there *is* a difference, because

```
<img src="IMAGES/image.jpg"> # => /ABOUT/IMAGES/image.jpg

<img src="/IMAGES/image.jpg"> # => /IMAGES/image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The "safety" of using relative URLs depends on if you will be using subdirectories in your URLs.

Assuming your file structure,

If you are at http://example.com/index.php, then the url `IMAGES/image01.jpg` will work.

If you are at http://example.com/somedir/index.php, then `"IMAGES/image01.jpg` will  not load (It will be looking for `http://example.com/somedir/IMAGES/image01.jpg` instead of your intended `http://example.com/IMAGES/image01.jpg`)

This means that using relative URLs is "dangerous" if you:

1) Move or copy your index.php file into a subdirectory
2) Use url rewriting to remove index.php from your URLs (and so hae URLs like example.com/some/location rewrite to `example.com/index.php?l=some/location`)

**Your safest bet is to use a variable to get your base URL:**

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
```

Then later in your HTML:

```
<img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/IMAGES/image01.jpg" alt="" />
```

If you move your site in the future, you can change the BASE_URL constant.

Answer (score -1):

Both should work, but I'd suggest using the slash. When you add the slash before hand, it means to look in the top most directory. With out it it means relative to the current file.

If you use the method with the slash before hand it allows you to move the file, or copy html to other files and it won't matter where they are.

On a side note, without the slash is called a relative path, and with the slash is called and absolute path.